# Why i am not able to cast pointer to the class structure

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `Geometry` class

```
class Geometry
{
public: 
    std::string stdstrType;
    bool bValid;
public:
    Geometry()

    Geometry( std::string strType , bool bValue )

    Geometry(const Geometry &g)

    ~Geometry()     
    virtual void draw();
    bool isValid();
    void setValidState(bool bState);
    virtual void Init();
    std::string GetName();  
};
```

Which is the base class for `Geometry` objects like in this case for `Sphere` class

```
class Sph : public Geometry
{
public:
    Sph( float radius , float segments );
    ~Sph();
    void init();
    void CleanUp();
    void draw();

private:
    float fRadius, fSegments;
    bool isInited;
    unsigned int m_VAO, m_VBO;
    int iNumsToDraw;
    SumShader shader;
    bool isChanged;
};
```

I have a Tree structure holding different `Container` objects and `Geometry` is a data type in the `Container` object.

```
class Container
{
private:
    std::string stdstrContainerName;
    std::string stdstrPluginType;
    Geometry Geom;
}
```

Since each item in the tree can hold a circle sphere or rectangle so I would like to use the draw function of geometry to draw the `Geometry` object types.
For this when I try to cast any `Geometry` Object type to `Geometry` I get an error.

```
Sph sphere(0.1 , 32);
Geometry *geom = &sphere;
Container cont("Sphere" , "SPHERE" , *geometry );   
myModel->SetContainer(child, cont);
```

The Constructor for Container

```
 Container::Container( std::string strName, std::string strType, const 
 Geometry& geometry) : Geom(geometry)
  { 
     stdstrContainerName = strName;
     stdstrPluginType = strType;
  }

 void  TreeModel::SetContainer(const QModelIndex &index, Container Cont)
  {
    TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
    item->setContainer(Cont);
  }


  class TreeItem
   {
    public:
     // Functions here
   private:
     QList<TreeItem*> childItems;
     Container itemData;
     TreeItem* parentItem;
   };
```

1) Is this the correct approach?

2) How can I cast the `Geometry` objects to the `Geometry` pointer?

Comment: It looks to me like you don't really understand pointers and dynamic memory. You create a new Geometry then immediately leak it by saying geom = &sphere. We don't have your Container constructor so we have no idea if that makes sense (and what is the variable "geometry" ? We have "geom" but not "geometry" . We also don't have  myModel and so don't know what it's SetContainer() looks like (nor do we know what variable "child" is).

Comment: You've declared `sphere` as a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Sph`. (Search for "most vexing parse".) Remove the `()`.

Comment: On a side note, `new` is not for creating pointers, it's for creating objects. Write `Geom* geom = &sphere;`.

Comment: Also note that your `Container` only holds `Geometry` instances and none of its derived types. Read about "slicing" and polymorphism in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: You definitely need to learn about inheritance. The object geom has nothing to do with a sphere, it's just a geometry. Geometry* geom = new Sphere() : this is a sphere.

Comment: Hi in order to simplify my code i made some errors in the demo code  which i have corrected now.

Comment: You may also want to use a good C++ book, because you are creating lots and lots of temporary objects for no good reason. And there is the critical issue of the storage of a stack object in a container after the object is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
Sph sphere();
```

You have declared a function wich return a Sphere object and take no parameters.

To declare an object to Sph you just simple write

`Sph sphere;` or `Sph sphere{};`

I guess you tried the first but it didn't compile, so you just changed the signature "until compiled".
You have declared a **custom constructor**, which means the compiler does not provide you anymore a **default constructor** so you can't declare a variable without calling the correct constructor (and in your case it wouldn't have sense).

In addition with

```
Geometry *geom = new Geometry;
geom = &sphere;
```

you're creating a new pointer geometry than leaking it immediatly and reassigning to a sphere geometry which has no sense at all.

Moreover all your method are public in Geometry and this does not have sense (why putting bool valid public and then a getter?).

in addition class `Container` is holding an instance to a base class which will give you issues due to object slicing, you need to use a pointer or a reference.

for just answering to your question you should instance a sphere with

```
Geometr* geom = new Sphere(1, 5); // random numbers
```

but the most genuine and honest thing I can tell is to rewrite everything from scratch and before that to study a little more trying with an easier example.

Answer (score -1):

The minimal code that works and implements an idea in the question:

```
#include <iostream>

class Geometry
{
public:
    Geometry(const std::string type) { stdstrType = type; }
    std::string GetName() { return stdstrType; }
    virtual void draw() {} ;
private:
    std::string stdstrType;
};

class Sphere : public Geometry
{
public:
    Sphere(float radius): Geometry("Sphere ") { fRadius = radius; }
    virtual void draw() { std::cout << GetName() << fRadius << "\n";}
private:
    float fRadius;
};

class Container
{
public:
    Container(std::string strName, Geometry* g)
    {
        stdstrContainerName = strName;
        geometry = g;
    }
    void draw() { geometry->draw(); }
private:
    std::string stdstrContainerName;
    Geometry *geometry;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Sphere sphere(0.1);
    Geometry *geom = &sphere;
    Container cont("Sphere container", geom);
    cont.draw();
    return 0;
}
```

Xcode 10.2.1: No Buildtime/Runtime Issues. Output:

```
Sphere 0.1
Program ended with exit code: 0
```